# Examples of non-uniqueness of the equilibrium states

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, thermodynamic-formalism

Let $f:X\rightarrow X$ be an Axiom $A$ diffeomorphism on a compact metric space $X$. Assume that $\phi:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is Hölder continuous. [R. Bowen](https://www.cpht.polytechnique.fr/sites/default/files/Bowen_LN_Math_470_second_ed_v2013.pdf) shows that there is a unique equilibrium state for potential $t\phi$. I have following question:

> Can one give a simple example in which there are two distinct equilibrium measures for the potential $t\psi$, where $\psi$ a continuous function on a compact metric space $X$?

I looked at [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/1998528.pdf?refreqid=excelsior%3A17fde8bd8bcb054490d9e62281d506af), but I do not understand it pretty well. I am wondering if one can give a simple example.

Comment: That paper is the standard example. An easier example in the context of a shift space would be $\psi(x)=-c/n$ where $n=\min \{j:x_j\ne x_0\}$. This has non-unique equilibrium states (concentrated at the two fixed points) for all $c\ge 1$. The proof requires a bit of computation with entropy so is not completely straightforward. If you make $\psi(x)=1/\sqrt n$, the proof may(?) become a little easier? I’m not sure.